# Does Jasmine Have Anything Like MOQ's It.IsAny?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, moq, jasmine

MOQ is a mocking framework used in .Net. It has a method called It.IsAny. It's used when you want to say that a method should be called with an item of a particular type. For example, you might say:

```
someObject.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<int>());
```

and it wouldn't matter if you called SomeMethod with 1, 2, 3 or 400000, so long as it's an int. This differs from saying that you want a *specific* value to be sent in as a parameter. For example:

```
someObject.SomeMethod(2);
```

Is there anything similar in Jasmine? I want to say

```
expect(someObject.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith(It.IsAny<string>());
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
jasmine.any(String)
```

There is more examples in this [cheatsheet](https://www.thekua.com/atwork/2013/01/cheat-sheet-for-javascript-testing-with-jasmine/).

Comment: Awesome! Very strange that simple Google searches didn't figure this out for me.

Answer (score 2):

As covered by the other answer, `jasmine.any(String)` allows you to assert the parameter is of a certain type. There is also `jasmine.anything()` for occasions when you just want to assert that something other than `null` or `undefined` was passed in. Both methods are covered by [the jasmine documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/jasmine.html).

| Assertion | Call | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jasmine.any(String) | someObject.SomeMethod('Test string') | Pass |
| jasmine.any(String) | someObject.SomeMethod(5) | Fail |
| jasmine.any(String) | someObject.SomeMethod(null) | Fail |
| jasmine.any(String) | someObject.SomeMethod(undefined) | Fail |
| jasmine.anything() | someObject.SomeMethod('Test string') | Pass |
| jasmine.anything() | someObject.SomeMethod(5) | Pass |
| jasmine.anything() | someObject.SomeMethod(null) | Fail |
| jasmine.anything() | someObject.SomeMethod(undefined) | Fail |